# Generate a random interger within a case: in a Loop()

Tags: java

I have a functioning script for a game, which uses a Java Client.

I am trying to generate a random number upon a Loop each time the Case: comes up.

```
public int onLoop() throws InterruptedException {

    switch (getState()) {

        case ATTACK:
            Entity SeaGull = npcs.closest("Seagull");
                if(SeaGull.exists())  {
                SeaGull.interact("Attack");
                sleep(random(1500, 2000));
            }
                break;
        case ATTACKING:
             int decide = random(1, 3);
                if(myPlayer().isAnimating()) {
                    getSkills().hoverSkill(Skill.STRENGTH);
                    log("Checking Stats...");
                    sleep(random(1000, 9000));
                }else if(decide == 3) {
                    getMouse().moveOutsideScreen();
                    sleep(random(5000, 30000));
                    log("AFKing");
                }
                break;
```

Here is what I am using to generate a random int:

```
int decide = random(1, 3);
```

and trying to pull that number with:

```
else if(decide == 3) {
```

But I have had no luck!

Comment: Java is not Javascript, please be careful!

Comment: Sorry, I was certain I tagged JS not Java, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @JasonEfthimiou This is Java, it's not JavaScript.

Comment: Makes sense because I've had to compile this and you cannot compile Javascript.

Comment: You... don't even know what you're using?

Comment: It's just that someone comments one thing and edits my post, this is besides the point. I am here to learn new techniques, can someone answer my simple question. I know it is not difficult and I can really use this method to improve my other scripts. TY

Comment: @JasonEfthimiou We don't have enough information to answer your question. What's exactly isn't working? Is it returning a number from 1-3, are you checking it? Does the `random()` function work, where is it defined? When is `myPlayer().isAnimating()` true, what about `ATTACKING`? etc...

Comment: AHA! (myPlayer().isAnimating() && decide == 3) TY TY. I forgot to make sure that isAnimating() is true during the else if

Answer (score 0):

```js
function numbers(objID) {
  var rand_inta = Math.floor(Math.random()*5); // Get first number
  document.getElementById(objID).innerHTML=(rand_inta); //Print it all into the second box
}
```

```html
<span id="numbers"></span><br>
<a onclick="numbers('numbers')"> <input type="submit" value="Get Random Number">
```

Comment: Need something that generates a random num between 0-4 [1,2,3] every time the script loops through the ATTACKING case.

Comment: The asker was mistaken originally. They need Java, not Javascript.

Comment: math.random if it's javascript

Comment: if it's java:  randomNum = minimum + (int)(Math.random()*5);

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the responses I have figured out the problem

```
case ATTACKING:
             int decide = random(1, 3);
             log(decide);
                if(myPlayer().isAnimating() && decide != 3) {
                    getSkills().hoverSkill(Skill.STRENGTH);
                    log("Checking Stats...");
                    sleep(random(1000, 9000));
                }else if(myPlayer().isAnimating() && decide == 3) {
                    getMouse().moveOutsideScreen();
                    sleep(random(5000, 30000));
                    log("AFKing");
                }
                break;
```